# library not found - Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, compiler-errors

Im getting a compiler error when switching my active target to iPad. No errors occur when the active target is set to iPhone.

I tried modifying 'Library Search Paths' to the following below, but no luck.
 - $(inherited)
 - \"$(SRCROOT)\"
 - \"$(SRCROOT)/Classes\"

```
ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalytics
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

-GoogleAnalytics lives in Classes/thirdparty/libGoogleAnalytics.a   Classes/thirdparty/GANTracker.h

Is there a property build setting Im missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library path searching is not recursive. You will need to explicitly add the `Classes/thirdparty` path for libraries within that directory to be found by the linker.

Comment: Means what sorry but i am facing the same issue.