# How to fix library bugs?

Tags: iphone, xcode, barcode

i am using barcode API in my app, When i am trying to build the App for test on iphone it shows the following error...
"
library not found for -lbardecode
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have'nt included the `barcode API` related `library (framework)` in your project,

**Edited:** Find your solution with the below SO post ..

[library not found - Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714546/library-not-found-command-developer-platforms-iphonesimulator-platform-develop)

Comment: @Anand : Go through the tutorial  for adding custom framework in your project    http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/Linking_Custom_Frameworks_from_your_Xcode_Projects

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem as follows:

Under Search Paths, double click on Library Search paths and add the following:

```
$(SRCROOT)/libbardecode/Release$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)
```

This will then link with the correct version of libbardecode.a whichever target you use.